# Understanding the binodal and spinodal curve in phase transitions

Tags: thermodynamics, phase-transition

Consider the following graph, which shows the Gibbs free energy per particle for a Van der Waals gas (the x axis is volume per particle, $v$ and the y axis is free Gibbs energy $G$):
[image: Gibbs free energy per particle for a Van der Waals gas]

Each curve has been drawn for a given and fixed value of $P$ and $T$. I have several questions:

- My professor said that the red courbe corresponds to a temperature above the critical temperature, the blue one to the critical temperature, and the black one to a temperature below the critical point. I want to know if the following argument is valid to explain this:

> The extreme principle for the Gibbs free energy states that the equilibrium value for any internal parameter (in this case $v$) is the one that minimises $G$ over the set of states for which $P$ and $T$ are fixed. Since the red curve has a single minimum, there is only one phase, so its temperature is higher than $T_c$. As for the black curve, there are two minima, both of them corresponding to the same value of $G$, thus there are two possible phases (liquid corresponding to the smaller minimum, and gas corresponding to the higher minimum) and the temperature has to be smaller to $T_c$.

- Can our system have a value of $v$ in between the two minima? I think that this would correspond to a coexistance of phases because the volume per particle is between the valaues corresponding to both phases, but then $g$ would not be minimum and the minimum principle would not be satisfied, so both phases could not cohexist at equilibrium. However, I know that two phases can coexist at equilibrium. What point of the graph would that correspond to?
- My professor said that to find the *binodal curve*, we have to take the minima of the curves at different $T$, and to find the *spinodal curve* the inflection points. Moreover, he also said that regions within the binodal curve correspond to coexistance of phases, points in between the spinodal and binodal curves to metastable states, and points inside the spinodal are unstable. Why does this happen? And how are the binodal and spinodal curves defined?
- Finally, for a temperature $T < T_c$ and a given pressure, would we always find two minima corresponding to the same value of $g$ in the graph or does this only happen for particular pairs $(P, T)$? To be more precise, if I fix the tempeature of the black curve and change $P$, would the new curve for $g$ still have to minima with the same value or would they be different? I ask this question because when we look at phase diagrams. such as the one in the image bellow, the coexistence of phases is usually only allowed for particular pairs $(P, T)$.
  [image]

Any help is welcomed, as well as further reading. Thanks in advance.